# How to Group_Concat with a 3-table JOIN for genealogy

Tags: sql, join, group-concat

I am failing to grasp how I can get the following outcome. I thought perhaps via GROUP_CONCAT, but I am also joining on 3 tables, and unclear on the correct syntax or if this is even the best approach.

Generic table layout:

**Table Users:** user_id | first | last
**Table Orgs** org_id | org_name
**Table Relationship**  user_id | org_id | start_year | end_year

The relationship table has MANY entries, that may be associated with that specific user_id.

I need to get the User columns: id, first, last. I'd like to try and group the org data into 1 concatenated, delimited field. Maybe a double group_concatenation is needed? Which would consist of the org_id, org_name, start_year & end_year for all records in the relationship table that match the user_id. I'm hoping for an output like this:

Each '|' represents a new column/piece of data.

If there was only 1 org_id associated with the user_id, the output would be (similar) to:

```
user_id | first | last | org_id-org_name-start_year-end_year
```

If there were more than 1 org found/associated with that user_id, the output would have more concatenated/delimited data in the same column:

```
user_id | first | last | org_id-org_name-start_year-end_year^org_id-org_name-start_year-end_year^org_id-org_name-start_year-end_year
```

(Notice the '-' delimiter between values and the '^' delimiter between new 'org-grouped' data.)

When I grab that data, I can then just break it up (on the backend/PHP side of things) into an array or whatever.

I'm not sure how I can GROUP_CONCAT (if that is even the best approach here?) while I have to JOIN on 3 separate tables.

This is not my REAL query. (I'm not sure if I should post it, as I do not want to cause any confusion as it does NOT match my dummy table/column names.)

I just wanted to show my attempt that gets me 3 individual rows, (using my JOINS) but no GROUP_CONCAT stuff:

```
SELECT genealogy_users.imis_id, genealogy_users.full_name,
    genealogy_users.member_email, genealogy_orgs.org_id,
    genealogy_orgs.org_name, genealogy_relations.user_id,
    genealogy_relations.relation_type, genealogy_relations.start_year,
    genealogy_relations.end_year 
FROM genealogy_users 
INNER JOIN genealogy_relations ON genealogy_users.imis_id = genealogy_relations.user_id 
INNER JOIN genealogy_orgs ON genealogy_relations.org_id = genealogy_orgs.org_id 
WHERE genealogy_users.imis_id = '00003';
```

UPDATE:

Well I seemed to have fudged my way through it. But I'm not sure how legit this is.

Its -ALMOST- there. I believe I still need a JOIN or something?  Since the `genealogy_orgs.org_id = '84864'` is hardcoded, and it should NOT be. Maybe it needs to come from a JOIN or something?

```
SELECT genealogy_users.*,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(org_id,'-',
        (SELECT org_name FROM genealogy_orgs WHERE genealogy_orgs.org_id = '84864'),
        '-',start_year,'-',end_year,'^')
    FROM genealogy_relations WHERE genealogy_relations.user_id = genealogy_users.imis_id
    ) AS alumni_list
FROM genealogy_users
WHERE genealogy_users.imis_id = '00003';
```

UPDATE 2:

My final attempt, which I think is getting me what I need. (But it's late, and I'll check back tomorrow and look at things more closely.)

```
SELECT genealogy_users.imis_id, genealogy_users.full_name,
    genealogy_users.member_email, genealogy_orgs.org_id,
    genealogy_orgs.org_name, genealogy_relations.user_id,
    genealogy_relations.relation_type, genealogy_relations.start_year,
    genealogy_relations.end_year,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(org_id,'-',org_name,'-',start_year,'-',end_year,'^')
    FROM genealogy_relations
    WHERE genealogy_relations.user_id = genealogy_users.imis_id
    ) AS alumni_list
FROM genealogy_users 
INNER JOIN genealogy_relations ON genealogy_users.imis_id = genealogy_relations.user_id 
INNER JOIN genealogy_orgs ON genealogy_relations.org_id = genealogy_orgs.org_id 
WHERE genealogy_users.imis_id = '00003';
```

Is there anything to make note of in the above attempt? Or is there a better approach? Hopefully something easily readable so it makes sense?

Comment: I agree with your rollbacks in this case, @whispers. Adding aliases to SQL queries is an example of changing code, rather than tidying.